# Multiple functions for a class does not store previous results

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11

## Problem

I want to create a function inside a class which `function2` will use the result generated from `function1`. I have a small code snippet where I tried to make it easy to understand.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
  
class GreaterSmaller { 
public: 
    int greater, smaller; 
}; 
  
GreaterSmaller findGreaterSmaller(int a, int b) 
{ 
    GreaterSmaller s; 
    if (a > b) { 
        s.greater = a; 
        s.smaller = b; 
    } 
    else { 
        s.greater = b; 
        s.smaller = a; 
    } 
  
    return s; 
} 
GreaterSmaller print() 
{ 
    GreaterSmaller s; 
    std::cout << s.greater << s.smaller << std::endl; 
} 
  

int main() 
{ 
    int x = 4;
    int y = 3; 
    GreaterSmaller result; 
 
    result = findGreaterSmaller(x, y); 
    result = print(); // I want it to print 4 & 3
  
    return 0; 
}
```

P.s Just wanted to mention I am not trying to print the result in the `function2` I have created that for a demo.

Comment: You have several unrelated instances of `GreaterSmaller`;

Comment: Have you tried passing a `GreaterSmaller` instance to `print`?

Comment: You keep returning and using new objects. Did you want to use class member functions and operate on a single  `GreaterSmaller` object? BTW, I am not indicating that you can't get it done using free functions just that you probably want class member functions and operating on a single instance.

Comment: You're also risking undefined behavior.

Comment: *"I have a small code snippet where I tried to make it easy to understand."* -- It might be better to rely on text to describe the desired functionality than to rely on non-functioning code to describe the functionality that the code does not have. (Plus, sometimes forcing yourself to write out a **detailed** description will lead you to spot problems.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the second method as taking an argument of the first type, and pass it when you call it, as such:

```
void print(GreaterSmaller &s) 
{ 
    std::cout << s.greater << s.smaller << std::endl; 
} 

print(result); // I want it to print 4 & 3
```

Comment: Why a reference? Would the `operator<<()` change that parameter?